# Angular 9 *ngIf is not a known property of div even with CommonModule imported

Tags: angular, angular9

Ever since we upgrade to angular 9 we keep getting this error that we can't use *ngIf.
It only complains on run time. no build errors.
We have about 10 lazy loaded modules.
The main module has the import for BrowserModule.
All the child modules have the import for CommonModule.
It works if we run it with ng serve --prod. but just plain ng serve it refuses.
This is making development a huge hassle as it takes way longer to compile after every change.
The error we are getting is: Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

```
<div class="m-grid__item m-grid__item--fluid  m-grid__item--order-tablet-and-mobile-1 m-login__wrapper" *ngIf="dataLoaded">
```

that is what its complaining about.
We are on Angular 9.0.5 with all our other libraries on latest aswell.

We are lazy loading the modules via routes.

```
path: 'login',
loadChildren: () => import('./unauthenticated/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
```

please don't mark this as a duplicate as i have tried every single thing on the internet i can find but nothing seems to work.

here is the tsconfig incase its a setting.

```
{
   "compileOnSave": false,
   "compilerOptions": {
   "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "declaration": false,
   "module": "esnext",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

App module imports

```
imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CommonModule,
    OverlayModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    NotificationModule
],
```

This is the auth module which is one of the affected modules.
The current scenario is for the AuthComponent.
The problem are on all modules.

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NotificationModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    RouterModule.forChild([
        {
            path: '',
            component: AuthComponent
        }
    ]),
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule
],
providers: [AuthClient, GlobalClient, NotificationHelperService, DealerClient, UserClient, AuthenticationService, SignalRService],
declarations: [
    AuthComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    AuthNoticeComponent,
    EulaComponent,
    ActivateAccountComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent,
    LoginTwoFactorAuthenticationComponent,
    BaseAuthComponent,
    ChangeEmailComponent,
    DealersNotFoundComponent,
    SystemOfflineComponent,
    DealersSuspendedComponent
]
```

Comment: also adding browser module to any of our other modules confirms that it has being imported by our main module since we get an error saying so

Comment: can you please add the actual error you are getting?

Comment: facing same issue with 9.1.2 even with common module imported throws *ngIf can't bind error

Answer (score 1):

Your main module should have
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

Comment: it does. I have tried it with only adding CommonModule to main module and adding it to every single module. no difference

Comment: and BrowserModule instead ? with a simple project, just need to import  BrowserModule in app module to use *ngIf

Comment: i have BrowserModule in my main module (app module)

Comment: and your component is declared in a module which import CommonModule ? if you remove your CommonModule in appmodule and keep only in specific module?

Comment: see the edit i made.
I have tried removing it from AppModule and only adding to the required modules. Same effect

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your html template you didn't use `**ngIf` instead of `*ngIf` or try *ngIf="dataLoaded==true" instead of *ngIf="dataLoaded"